# Build Plan error when depending on git package with extra-deps

Tags: git, haskell, haskell-stack

I need some way to share private code between internal packages. In this case, I have a project, called `cra-products` which depends on `risk-types`. `risk-types` needs to be shared between several projects, and it cannot be public.

I'm using stack and the packages node to depend on `risk-types` like this:

```
packages:
- '.'
- location:
   git: git@git.xxxx.com:risk/risk-types.git
   commit: 9653ca15
  extra-dep: true
```

But `risk-types` itself depends on other code not in the index: `refined`, [which is on Hackage](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/refined), and `validated-types`, [which is something I wrote on github](https://github.com/seanhess/validated-types) (haven't published it yet, because I'm still working on it).

Here's `risk-types`' stack.yaml:

```
packages:
- '.'
- location:
   git: https://github.com/seanhess/validated-types.git
   commit: fc59f3d
  extra-dep: true
extra-deps:
- validated-types-0.1.0.0
- refined-0.1.2.1
```

When I got to build `cra-products`, I get this error:

```
$ stack build

Warning: Some extra-deps are neither installed nor in the index:
    * risk-types-0.1.0.0

Error: While constructing the build plan, the following exceptions were encountered:

In the dependencies for risk-types-0.1.0.0:
    refined must match -any, but the stack configuration has no specified version (latest applicable is 0.1.2.1)
    validated-types must match -any, but the stack configuration has no specified version
needed due to cra-products-0.1.0.0 -> risk-types-0.1.0.0

Recommended action: try adding the following to your extra-deps in /Users/seanhess/projects/simple/cra-products/stack.yaml:
- refined-0.1.2.1
```

Even if I add `refined` to the extra-deps section of `cra-products`, I still get an error for `validated-types`. I don't want to have to do this, because my project doesn't currently depend directly on either of those, just on `risk-types`. How can I fix this?

Comment: Well, the project has to specify versions of all transitive dependencies somehow, and the straight forward way to do that is to add them to the `extra-deps` as suggested. `stack` currently respects only a single `stack.yaml`, so `risk-types`'s `stack.yaml` is ignored. If you want to avoid redundantly declaring extra-deps in multiple `stack.yaml`s, the easiest way might be to move all internal packages into a common stack project.

Comment: Oh, maybe there's an alternative to moving everything into a single stack project: Define a [custom snapshot](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/custom_snapshot/) that includes your extra-deps!

Comment: Thanks. Your comment about there being only one stack.yaml makes things much clearer.